# A moving object falling onto a conveyer belt whose surface has friction

Tags: forces, friction

[image]

Suppose the object is falling down and surface of conveyer placed on the ground has a co-efficient of kinetic friction $\mu$. After some time of the object travelling, it falls onto the conveyer.

Now in the frame of conveyer, the block is moving towards left, and gets accelerated from a velocity of $ -v$ in direction opposite of conveyer belt's motion to a velocity of zero. How would I explain the same phenomena in the lab frame? As in the frame of an observer outside?

[image]

note: there is a force acting in direction opposite to which block was travelling originally but I have not drawn that because I want to emphasize the forces acting in direction along which conveyer is moving

Comment: Is the belt accelerating or moving with constant velocity v?

Comment: constant velocity 'v', Mr.Binod

Answer (score 1):

The conveyer belt rubs in  the forward direction against the bottom face of the block. Due to the blocks bottom surface not being smooth, the conveyer gets pushed back, and at the same time, the block is pushed forward due to the forward rub.

When the block picks up the same speed as the conveyer belt, the friction stops because there is no more rubbing between the surfaces. Having a velocity difference between block and surface is requirement for friction to kick in.

Comment: That is the correct answer,  however i would like to point that before achieving same velocity,  in the conveyer belt's frame the block will experience a pseudo force.